# How do I restrict a Django model to just one of several possible relationships?

Tags: python, django

Given these models, how do I prevent a FinancialTransaction from being assigned to more than one Thing?

In other words, if ThingOne has a FinancialTransaction, ThingTwo or ThingThree cannot have a relationship to it.

How do I enforce this in the admin?   I can of course get Thing* in the SomeThing admin with Inlines, but that allows me to set more than one Thing*.

My first inclination is that my modeling is wrong and that all Things should be represented by one model, but they're definitely different types of Things.

```
from django.db import models


class ThingOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    some_things = models.ForeignKey('FinancialTransaction', blank = True, null = True)


class ThingTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    some_things = models.ForeignKey('FinancialTransaction', blank = True, null = True)
    thingone = models.ForeignKey(ThingOne)


class ThingThree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    some_things = models.ForeignKey('FinancialTransaction', blank = True, null = True)
    thingtwo = models.ForeignKey(ThingTwo)


class FinancialTransaction(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: if they are different type of things then why not have a field in a single model to identify the different things e.g. type field

Comment: They are completely different types of things with many different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the relationship on the `FinancialTransaction` using a Generic foreign key.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class FinatialTransation(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then the relationship exists in one place and there can only be 1.

Then from the `FinancialTransaction` you check the object ID and the objects `ContentType` and look it up accordingly.

```
ft = FinancialTransaction.objects.get(...)
thing = ft.content_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=ft.object_id)
```

Additionally you can then limit the GenericForeignKey to certain content types with:

```
class FinatialTransation(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q(
        models.Q(app_label='yourappsname', model='ThingOne') | models.Q(app_label='yourappsname', model='ThingTwo') | models.Q(app_label='yourappsname', model='ThingThree')
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Oh, this is nice.  What is this object_pk?

Comment: Ah sorry, copy and paste error from my project.  object_pk == object_id (updated)